# How do you solve Error C Stack Usage 7970736 Too Close to Limit?

Tags: r, google-sheets

I'm trying to run Google Sheets in R and when I use `gs_ls()` to be able to view the sheets linked to my account it returns:

> Error C Stack Usage 7970736 Too Close To The Limit

---

> ```
> gs_auth(new_user = TRUE)
> Disabling .httr-oauth by renaming to .httr-oauth-SUSPENDED
> No token currently in force.
> Waiting for authentication in browser...
> Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
> Authentication complete.
> gs_ls()
> Error: C stack usage  7970736 is too close to the limit
> ```

Comment: I have the same issue. Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Same problem here...